# Maven SOLRJ version 7.6 increases thread

Tags: java, spring, maven, solr, solrj

If Maven dependency of **SOLRJ 7.x.x** is used instead of **SOLRJ 6.x.x** then the threads are increasing in every search request and does not decrease.

I am using **SOLR 7.6.0**, **Java 1.8.0_111** and **Apache Tomcat 8.0.39**.

For more clarification here is the image of thread using *htop*
[image]

From above image you can see the threads count is 744. In every search request it increases, even for testing I was able to increase upto 5131 using SOLRJ 7.6.0. But, using SOLRJ 6.x.x this increment does not occur.

**Note:** Threads are increasing in my application server, not in SOLR server.

Can you please suggest me what to do? I want to use SOLRJ 7.6.0, but can't due to that issue.

Comment: could you add more details, what does it mean about threads, could you show some additional info about this problem?

Comment: @Mysterion updated the question with image.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the version increase is the only change to your application? This problem fades away, when you rollback to the older version again?

Comment: @cheffe, yes, quite sure. I tried with every 7.x.x version against 6.x.x. Every 7.x.x increases the thread, whereas 6.x.x does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing java heap size.

SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms8g -Xmx10g"

Comment: did you try fine tuning or dynamic clustering ?

https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/tips-and-tricks-to-maximize-apache-solr-performance-74e8ea4f5c8d

Comment: I don't think it is required.